# removing specific strings from the end of the words c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can I do something like following to remove specific strings from the end of the words ?

```
public static HashSet<string> stringtoremove = new HashSet<string>
         ...............
         .................
    public static string stepone(this string word)
        {
            if (stringtoremove(word.EndsWith))
            {
             word =   ..................................;
            }
            return word;
        }
```

I tried but it doesn't work. did i miss something in my code ? thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to specify your requirements more precisely. Ordering is going to matter. For example, if `stringtoremove` (terrible name, btw - work on following .NET naming conventions)  contains "ab" and "xy" then what should the result be if you give it "123abxy"? What about "123xyab"?

Comment: @mudu,matching the end of each word, if it contains one of the  string in hash set them remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you actually want to look into the [`HashSet<String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx) to see if the given string parameter ends with one of these words. If so, remove it from the end of the string.

You can use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) to determine the first string in the set that is also the end of the given word:

```
var firstMatch = stringtoremove.FirstOrDefault(str => word.EndsWith(str));
if (firstMatch != null)
    return word.Substring(0, word.Length - firstMatch.Length);
else
    return word;
```

Comment: you assume true, but the (stringtoremove) is set of strings right ? or just one string?

Comment: @JoneMamni: Yes, it's a [`HashSet<String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx). That's why i've used [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) to determine the first string in the set that is also the end of the given word.

Comment: does this will look for the end of the word one time ? for example, let take the word (hello) and let we say the hash set contains the char (l) and (o). what the output would be?

Comment: @JoneMamni: It would remove the `o`, so the result would be `hell`. The  `FirstOrDefault` is just a hint that LINQ can finish when the first is found. Actually a HashSet cannot contain duplicates and the word can only end with one of the Strings in the HashSet.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to use Regular Expressions; have a look at the [Replace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx).

```
string input = "test testabc test123 abc abctest";
string pattern = @"(abc\b)";
string replacement = "";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);
```

Comment: this one will not remove from the end of the word. it would remove what match the pattern everywhere. but if use pattern like (^(ab|..|..|...), it may works

Comment: It does remove just the ends because of the `\b` word boundary. So 'testabc' becomes 'test', but 'abctest' is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [String.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) method?

```
word = word.TrimEnd(charsToTrim)
```

Comment: the (charsToTrim) must array, list, hash set of strings.